# Are these characteristic functions Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: general-topology, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to prepare myself for the final exam in real-analysis and I received this problem from my professor, could you help me, please?
 Let $E\subseteq[0,1]$ s.t. $E \notin \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})$, $A=[-1,1]$ $\setminus$$E$ and let $\chi_A$, $\chi_E$:$\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$ be the corresponding characteristic functions.
 Determine if the functions  $\chi_A$, $\chi_E$,  $\chi_A$+$\chi_E$,  $\chi_A$-$\chi_E$ are Lebesgue measurable.
 I was thinking that the characteristic functions are constant, so it follows immediately that are Lebesgue measurable, but I'm not sure if this is correct...

Comment: You are right only $\chi_A+\chi_E\equiv 1$ is measurable.

Comment: $\chi_A^{-1}(0)=\chi_E^{-1}(1)=\big(\chi_A-\chi_E\big)^{-1}(-1)$ all are equal to the non measurable set $E$.

Comment: $\chi_A+\chi_E=\chi_{[-1,1]}$ (not constant 1). Still measurable of course.

Comment: So only the third one is Lebesgue measurable?